# JavaEE Error starting tomcat9server: INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat9, eclipse-oxygen

I have created a Dynamic Web Project on eclipse oxygen IDE JAVA EE workspace with multiple HTML pages without web.xml. When I run it on eclipse by right clicking on the Project Explorer and run on the server I get the following error message. I have JavaSE 10.0.2 on the system.

Is it possible to tell me where I am wrong or what should I do?

> INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs.
>   Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that
>   were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs
>   during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time. Apr
>   22, 2019 5:36:21 AM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. By doing the following.

I had two JavaSE's. One is 1.8.171 and the other is 10.0.2

I uninstalled JavaSE 10.0.2 and jre10.0.2 and kept only 1.8.171.

And set up the environment inside eclipse for tomcat 9.

And that's it. Solved the problem. Also created a brand new Dynamic Web Project. And copied all the HTML files to proper places.